# How to call erc721 functions (approve, setApprovalForAll etc.) from another contract?

Tags: tokens, nft, erc-721, mint, factory

I have an **erc721 NFT** and a **Main contract**. The **Main Contract** is a **factory contract**. Which creates erc 721 contracts. I can create NFT contract from Main contract . But can't call the **approve**, **setApprovalForAll** functions as the **caller changed** to the Main contract address ( **as I am calling the functions from Main contract** ). I simply wanted to create and mint a **single nft** on the **owners address**. And other users can **buy the NFT of the owner**. But I am not able to call the **transferFrom** or other important functions from the **Main contract**. Is there any way to solve this ?
TIA

**ERC721 contract :**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
// Compatible with OpenZeppelin Contracts ^5.0.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/utils/ERC721Holder.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract NFT is ERC721, ERC721URIStorage, Ownable {
    address private immutable mainContract;
    address private immutable creator;
    uint256 private _nextTokenId;

    constructor(
        string memory initialName,
        string memory initialSymbol,
        address _creator
    ) ERC721(initialName, initialSymbol) Ownable(_creator) {
        mainContract = msg.sender;
        creator = _creator;
    }

    function safeMint(address to, string memory uri) public isAuth {
        uint256 tokenId = _nextTokenId++;
        _safeMint(to, tokenId);
        _setTokenURI(tokenId, uri);
    }

    // The following functions are overrides required by Solidity.

    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage)
        returns (string memory)
    {
        return super.tokenURI(tokenId);
    }

    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage)
        returns (bool)
    {
        return super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
    }

    modifier isAuth() {
        require(msg.sender == mainContract, "You are not allowed");
        _;
    }
}
```

**Main Contract:**

```
contract Main {
    NFT public nftAddr;
    address owner;

    constructor(){owner = msg.sender;}

    function createNFT() external {
        require(owner == msg.sender,"Only Owner can create");
        nftAddr = new NFT("MyNFT", "MNFT", owner );
    }

    function mintNFT(string memory uri) external{
        require(address(nftAddr) != address(0), "NFT contract not deployed");
        require(owner == msg.sender,"Only Owner can mint");
        nftAddr.safeMint(msg.sender, uri);
    }

    function buyNFT(address nftAddress) external  {
       //change the owner of tokenID to msg.sender((newOwner))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function in the NFT contract that calls the specific function you want for using the line like this: `nftAddr.safeMint(msg.sender, uri);`.

Example:

```
function transferNFT(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId) public isAuth {
    _transfer(from, to, tokenId);
}
```

You are trying to call a function that NFT contract has, so you cannot call safeMint function like that if you don't create a function like above. You have to use it directly: `_safeMint(msg.sender, uri);`.

Or you can place both contracts in the same file to use the functions directly. Also if you want to have seperate files, you can import the ERC contracts in Main contract as well.

Shortly, if you want to use ERC721 functions as a function of the NFT contract, you have to create functions that call the ERC721 functions. Or if you want to use them directly, you should have the import lines in your Main contract, so you can call them.

Hope you find your solution.